# Play Framework redirect not always work. Bug or my fault?

Tags: javascript, playframework

i am trying to redirect a user to another page in my play project. The problem is, the redirect works quite well in one view, but it doesnt work in another view.

The strange thing is, when i look at the console -, i can see that system has loaded the view (i can see this by setting system.out.println() command" but i cant see that happening in the browser view.

Working Code:

```
    public static void deleteMessages(boolean[] chbox)
{
    System.out.println("Checkbox count: "+chbox.length);
    String[] referer =Request.current().headers.get("referer").toString().split("/");
    String mailbox = referer[referer.length-2];
    String pageNumber ="/"+ referer[referer.length-1];
    for(int i = 0; i<chbox.length;i++)
    {
    String id=params.getAll("hdnchbox")[i].toString();
    if(mailbox.equals("inbox"))
    {
        MessageInbox m = MessageInbox.findById(Long.parseLong(id));
        m.delete();
    }else
    {
        MessageOutbox m = MessageOutbox.findById(Long.parseLong(id));
        m.delete();
    }

    }
    show(mailbox,Integer.parseInt(pageNumber));
}
```

Not Working Code:

```
    public static void deleteMessage(Long id, String mailbox)
{
    if(mailbox.toLowerCase().equals("inbox"))
    {
    MessageInbox msg = MessageInbox.findById(id);
    msg.delete();
    }
    else
    {
    MessageOutbox msg = MessageOutbox.findById(id);
    msg.delete();
    }
    System.out.println("Redirect URL: "+"/Messages/"+mailbox);
    String redirectURL = "/Messages/"+mailbox;
    show(mailbox,null);
}
```

The show void:

```
    public static void show(String messageBoxName,Integer pageNumber)
{
    if(pageNumber == null)
    {
        System.out.println("pagenumber null");
        pageNumber = 0;
    }
    List<UserMessage> msgs = messageList(pageNumber,messageBoxName);
    System.out.println("The page has loaded");
    render(pageNumber,msgs,messageBoxName);
}
```

The strangest part is i can both see the "The page has loaded" message in the system console, but i can see it in the browser window.

is it a bug, or am i doing something wrong?

(passing null value to show() works i tried that)

Comment: when you chain actions, framework issues a redirect request. Can you see this redirect happening from the firebug console?

Comment: firebug shows the post action and the webpage html code as response. i guess this is a bug. i also tried to change null value to 0 but still no hope..

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug with localVariables, I had a similar problems so times ago. Even if I reassign a variable like pageNumber, I got null in my template

Try calling "show(mailbox, 0)" instead of "show(mailbox,null)" to see if it solves your problem

Comment: nope it still doesnt work. the void works but it doesnt show the page.

Answer (score 0):

i've ended up redirecting with jquery instead of play redirect command. I think this is a bug in play framework. i can see the response html in firebug but no luck on the browser screen.